# Calculating the probability of random search in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, probability

What is the way, in Python, of computing the probability of finding two specific numbers, `X1` or `X2` (from random search) into a list of `N_T` elements where, for this, we random `n_s` times the list elements, which, by the way, is removed in each random step.

Does this code make sense?

```
 N = 2 # number of desired values to be dound (one OR another)

 n_s = 14110 # total number of random roll 
 N_T = 35960 #configurations (searching space)

 p = 0.0 # probability
 for i in range(1, n_s + 1):
      p = p + ( float(N) / (float(N_T) - (float(i) - 1.0) ) )

 print ("Probability of finding" + " '" + str(N) + "' different numbers  within '1..." + str(N_T) + "':", float(p))
```

Comment: None of those `float`s do anything.

Comment: this is a math problem - not  a computing one.  if both numbers are in your range and it contains no duplicate numbers its something like 2/35960 - for each of the 14110 tries, if you try it 14110 times and want the average thats mult/div by 14110 - if there are dupes or one or both are not part of your configuration it differs. Too few infos to do much.